Python Package lxml cant be installed on windows without internet
I am currently facing the problem that I would like to install the "lxml" library offline on a Windows computer. With an internet connection, it can be done using the command:
py -m pip install lxml
I have Python version 3.12.4 and pip version 24.0.
I have downloaded the library from "https://pypi.org" and then tried to manually install it using the command:
py -m pip install --no-index --find-links=C:\Users\user\Downloads lxml
However, I receive the following error message:
**Processing c:\users\user\Downloads\lxml-5.2.2.tar.gz
Installing build dependencies ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [3 lines of output]
Looking in links: c:\Users\user\Downloads
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Cython>=3.0.10 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Cython>=3.0.10
[end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.**
Accordingly, I tried to manually install the Cython package as well:
py -m pip install --no-index --find-links=C:\Users\user\Downloads --no-build-isolation Cython
However, I encountered another error message during the installation:
**Looking in links: c:\Users\user\Downloads
Processing c:\users\user\Downloads\cython-3.0.10.tar.gz
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: Cython
Building wheel for Cython (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× Building wheel for Cython (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [328 lines of output]
:118: DeprecationWarning: Use shutil.which instead of find_executable
Unable to find pgen, not compiling formal grammar.
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
.
.
.
.
copying Cython\Utility\TypeConversion.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\Cython\Utility
copying Cython\Utility\UFuncs_C.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\Cython\Utility
copying Cython\Utility\arrayarray.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\Cython\Utility
copying Cython\Utility\CppSupport.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\Cython\Utility
running build_ext
Compiling C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_9vhdr3w\cython_c01e00aa60fa4b1eab8e6aa8e223c69d\Cython\Compiler\Parsing.py because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_9vhdr3w\cython_c01e00aa60fa4b1eab8e6aa8e223c69d\Cython\Compiler\Parsing.py
building 'Cython.Compiler.Parsing' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
[end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for Cython
Failed to build Cython
ERROR: Could not build wheels for Cython, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
**
Can someone help me with this? I have already installed Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0, but it still doesn't work. Is there perhaps another way to install the lxml library? I found the following documentation (https://lxml.de/4.1/installation.html), but it looks more like a Linux guide to me, and it raises new questions.

Have you tried using pip's built in download command?
Probably looks something like this: python.exe -m pip download lxml --dest .
Does that download the same file as you did? If not, it seems likely you downloaded a version of that library incompatible with your python install.

The binary package for lxml on 64-bit Windows, CPython 3.12 is lxml-5.2.2-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (direct download link!) – what you have is the source tarball.

The typical way to solve this problem is with pip's download command which is specifically designed to address this.
In this case you probably want a command like this to download a single package:
python.exe -m pip download lxml --dest .
Which will dump the library (and potentially any/many dependencies) to whatever current directory your console is in, or you can change the dest to your desired directory.

Why didn't it work for you?
Looking at your file, it appears you downloaded the source code of the lxml library, not the whl appropriate for your python install. I was able to replicate your errors using that same file, but had no issues when attempting to offline install the version downloaded by pip which is matched to my python install.
I highly recommend this answer which discusses requirements files as the generally recommended solution to this type of situation.
Let me know if you have any questions.
